# Rolling file appenders do not work, need help understanding

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

I am confused.
When I had SpringBoot Logback installed, SpringBoot would rotate the log files. Yet, due to a compatibility problem with a library, I had to switch to log4j. Logging still works, but the rotating log files no longer do.

My pom.xml includes:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-spring-boot</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My application.properties file includes:

```
# Logging pattern for file
logging.pattern.file= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.file-name-pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n"
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size=5MB
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history=100
```

Yet, the logs do not rotate any longer like they did when I used Logback.

I am not sure if I need a separate log4j.properties file (I don't think so) or what exactly is off - that is, why the log files no longer rotate.

Would appreciate suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: You still use logback properties and wonder why log4j2 won't work as expected? More here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html Afaik, log4j2 requires its own dedicated configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the great help! As Slevin above noted, my main problem was that I didn't have the config file for log4j2. And, also, I needed to add a "sys:" to be able to read the environment variable for the path to the file to write. All good now!